# Selecting from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  the following tables below.

```
athletes
+------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| idATHLETES | ATHLETENAME     | TEAMS_idTEAMS | TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+
| JG         | JUSTIN GATLIN   | USA-TF-MEN    | USA                     |
| MS         | MARIA SHARAPOVA | RUS-WTA       | RUS                     |
| SW         | SERENA WILLIAMS | USA-WTA       | USA                     |
| UB         | USAIN BOLT      | JAM-TF-MEN    | JAM                     |
| VW         | VENUS WILLIAMS  | USA-WTA       | USA                     |
+------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+

EVENTS 

+------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+
| idEVENTS   | EVENTNAME     | ATHLETES_idATHLETES | ATHLETES_TEAMS_idTEAMS | ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY |
+------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+
| ATH        | ATHLETICS     | JG                  | USA-TF-MEN             | USA                              |
| ATH        | ATHLETICS     | UB                  | JAM-TF-MEN             | JAM                              |
| TEN        | TENNIS        | MS                  | RUS-WTA                | RUS                              |
| TEN        | TENNIS        | VW                  | USA-WTA                | USA                              |
| TEN-DOUBLE | TENNIS DOUBLE | SW                  | USA-WTA                | USA                              |
| TEN-DOUBLE | TENNIS DOUBLE | VW                  | USA-WTA                | USA                              |
+------------+---------------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------------+

RESULTS
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| idRESULTS | STATUS      | MEDALS | EVENTS_idEVENTS | EVENTS_ATHLETES_idATHLETES | EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_idTEAMS | EVENTS_ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
| results1  | DID-NOT-WIN | SILVER | TEN             | MS                         | RUS-WTA                       | RUS                                     |
| results1  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN             | VW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     |
| results2  | DID-NOT-WIN | BRONZE | ATH             | JG                         | USA-TF-MEN                    | USA                                     |
| results2  | WON         | GOLD   | ATH             | UB                         | JAM-TF-MEN                    | JAM                                     |
| results3  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN-DOUBLE      | SW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     |
| results3  | WON         | GOLD   | TEN-DOUBLE      | VW                         | USA-WTA                       | USA                                     |
+-----------+-------------+--------+-----------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

How can I get a list Athletes who participate in more than one Event

1. and  won at least one of them
2. and won none of them

I have come out with this code below but this returns the wrong output ?

```
SELECT idATHLETES, ATHLETENAME, EVENTNAME FROM athletes
JOIN EVENTS ON idATHLETES = ATHLETES_idATHLETES
JOIN RESULTS ON events.ATHLETES_idATHLETES = RESULTS.EVENTS_ATHLETES_idATHLETES
WHERE idEVENTS >=2 AND STATUS = 'WON'
```

Comment: how do you have an athlete who won at least one of them and won none of them?

Comment: Like two or more athletes where an athlete competes in two events and wins all whilst another athlete competes in another two or more events and wins none of them...

Comment: ah, all in one result set? One query?

Comment: Two different queries one for each ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Athletes who participated in more than one Event and won at least one of them:**

```
select a.idATHLETES as id,a.ATHLETENAME as Name,count(*) as evtCount, 
SUM(CASE WHEN r.STATUS = 'WON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as victoryCount 
from athletes a 
join  EVENTS e 
on e.ATHLETES_idATHLETES = a.idATHLETES and e.ATHLETES_TEAMS_idTEAMS = a.TEAMS_idTEAMS and e.ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY = a.TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY 
join RESULTS r 
on r.EVENTS_idEVENTS=e.idEVENTS and r.EVENTS_ATHLETES_idATHLETES=e.ATHLETES_idATHLETES -- etc 
group by a.idATHLETES,a.ATHLETENAME 
having evtCount>1 and victoryCount>0 
order by a.idATHLETES,a.ATHLETENAME;
```

**Results:**

```
+----+----------------+----------+--------------+
| id | Name           | evtCount | victoryCount |
+----+----------------+----------+--------------+
| VW | VENUS WILLIAMS |        2 |            2 |
+----+----------------+----------+--------------+
```

**Athletes who participated in more than one Event and won none:**

```
select a.idATHLETES as id,a.ATHLETENAME as Name,count(*) as evtCount, 
SUM(CASE WHEN r.STATUS = 'WON' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as victoryCount 
from athletes a 
join  EVENTS e 
on e.ATHLETES_idATHLETES = a.idATHLETES and e.ATHLETES_TEAMS_idTEAMS = a.TEAMS_idTEAMS and e.ATHLETES_TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY = a.TEAMS_COUNTRY_idCOUNTRY 
join RESULTS r 
on r.EVENTS_idEVENTS=e.idEVENTS and r.EVENTS_ATHLETES_idATHLETES=e.ATHLETES_idATHLETES -- etc 
group by a.idATHLETES,a.ATHLETENAME 
having evtCount>1 and victoryCount=0 
order by a.idATHLETES,a.ATHLETENAME;
```

**Results:**

no rows returned, you lack data for that

### Notes

This is just a `group by with having`, and conditional aggregation (plus really messed up column names) :p

Answer (score 1):

You can use having to get the records where there are at least two events and status = 'won' at least once.

```
SELECT idATHLETES, ATHLETENAME, EVENTNAME FROM athletes
JOIN EVENTS ON idATHLETES = ATHLETES_idATHLETES
JOIN RESULTS ON events.ATHLETES_idATHLETES = RESULTS.EVENTS_ATHLETES_idATHLETES AND RESULTS.Status = 'WON'
HAVING COUNT(idEVENTS) >=2 AND COUNT(STATUS) >= 1
```